# Xamarin forms: Display the title, subtitle and numbered points in UI from HTML data

Tags: html, string, xamarin.forms

I converted HTML data into string using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/ceee/ReadSharp/blob/master/ReadSharp/HtmlUtilities.cs). But I need to format the text again like the following.

[image]

Sample HTML data added on [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hRrUdGSUy9QhKBIej32ekl-nQ-vvvFon).

My text has a title, subtitle, and numbered points. So how can I change the data like the above screenshot?

Comment: I solved the numbered point alignment issue using a webview. For more details please go through this thread. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/392205#Comment_392205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plugin [HtmlLabelPlugin](https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin)

Install it in every Xamarin.Forms project from nuget.

#### iOS: AppDelegate.cs

```
HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
```

#### Android: MainActivity.cs

```
HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
```

#### in xaml

```
xmlns:htmlLabel="clr-namespace:LabelHtml.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=HtmlLabel.Forms.Plugin"
```

```
<htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding HtmlString}"/>
```

Comment: Still, the numbered points are not aligned correctly, I need a left alignment for numbered points. Is that possible? Current screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yHEsPOjiG3pu-kW-SbYGYTn9TrDOZtQu

Comment: I think it because the plugin doesn't support party of tag in html

Comment: If you need to customize something in Android or iOS you can use inline CSS, for example:

`<span style="color: red">1.</span>`

Comment: Why do you want to display it in label ? It is not a wise method . You can display it on webview or  as pdf .

Comment: Some format will display because of css style ,but it will not work when display on label.

Comment: I tried webview, but the same problem is also there.

Comment: This is a REST API call response, how can I show it in PDF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200807/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/392205#Comment_392205

Comment: OK, I will check it :)

Answer (score 1):

Add TextType to a Label and bind the html code on Text property

```
<Label x:Name="HtmlLbl" TextType="Html">
```

Comment: The property 'Text Type' was not found in type 'Label'

Comment: I am using latest xamarin forms version 4.2.0.848062

Comment: I use Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.778476-pre1 and i have this property

Comment: Still, the numbered points are not aligned correctly, I need a left alignment for numbered points. Is that possible? Current screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yHEsPOjiG3pu-kW-SbYGYTn9TrDOZtQu/view

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/392205#Comment_392205